# How to write FreeBSD image to USB flash drive

Tags: boot, usb-flash-drive, freebsd, bootable-media

I am trying to write `FreeBSD-10.3-RELEASE-amd64-memstick.img` to a USB flash drive, in the hopes of installing FreeBSD on an x64 computer in my house. Here is the image: `ftp://ftp.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD/releases/amd64/amd64/ISO-IMAGES/10.3/`.

I have searched up how to write `.img` files to a USB flash drive, with most sites saying to use **Unetbootin**, **Startup Disk Creator**, or the **dd command**. When I plugged in and selected the flash drive after using Unetbootin, I received the message "Missing operating system". With Disk Creator, I received a message telling me that Disk Creator couldn't write the image to the flash drive.

As for the **dd command**, I used this: `dd if=FreeBSD-10.3-RELEASE-amd64-memstick.img of=/dev/sdb1 bs=10240 conv=sync`, which I got from [here](https://www.freebsd.org/releases/10.1R/announce.html) and [here](https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/38934/). The command writes a bunch of garbage files to my flash drive, instead of the contents of the FreeBSD image (which I assume wouldn't be garbage files).

How should I go about writing FreeBSD to the flash drive and installing it to my computer, given that these options didn't work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you are using dd within FreeBSD or Linux:

Using Linux:

1) `umount /dev/sdb`

If your USB stick is under /dev/sdb

2) `dd if=FreeBSD-10.3-RELEASE-amd64-memstick.img of=/dev/sdb bs=10240`

Using (Free)BSD:

1) `umount /dev/da0`

If your USB stick is under /dev/da0

2) `dd if=FreeBSD-10.3-RELEASE-amd64-memstick.img of=/dev/da0 bs=1m`

Please note the `of=/dev/sdb` argument as you are supposed to write to the whole stick instead of its first partition.

The same is true of `of=/dev/da0`. But please note that `da` is *typically* the prefix for USB port devices on (Free)BSD. Which means that it might just as well be `da1`. So make sure to check beforehand. :)

Easiest way would be to compare the results of an `ls /dev` before and after plugging/unplugging your flash drive/USB stick.

3) Now reboot and choose the USB stick as the boot option.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the part about sdb instead of sdb!
    
For anybody using cygwin for this, make sure you started cygwin as administrator. you can find out what /dev/sdb or similar you should use with `cat /proc/partitions`.
    
To see if dd is making progress, append `status=progress` to the dd command.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to write the image to USB on Windows, try [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/). Choose your USB drive under `Device`, check `Create a bootable disk using` and select `DD Image` from the drop down, browse to the image file and hit `Start`.

It is unclear from your description if your problem is solely with drive creation or with booting off a USB key that is likely good (the `dd` version should be good judging by the command and assuming `sdb` was the right device)

Answer (score 0):

As [mentionned](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/bsdinstall-pre.html) in the Handbook, under MS Windows, you can use [win32diskImager](https://sourceforge.net/projects/win32diskimager/).

1. Download the install ISO file.
2. Download the win32diskImager installer (it is now called ImageWriter)
3. Install win32diskImager  - a breeze
4. Launch it, choose your USB key, and browse for the ISO file
5. Click "Write", wait a few instants, and you are ready to boot!